# Check Redis server version

Tags: redis, version

**how to check Redis server version?**

I've found in [Redis site](http://redis.io/topics/quickstart) this command:

> $ redis-server

and that should give me (according to the site):

```
[28550] 01 Aug 19:29:28 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use 'redis-server /path/to/redis.conf'
[28550] 01 Aug 19:29:28 * Server started, Redis version 2.2.12
[28550] 01 Aug 19:29:28 * The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6379
... and so forth ...
```

but I get this instead:

```
[8719] 04 Feb 14:51:09.009 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
[8719] 04 Feb 14:51:09.009 # Unable to set the max number of files limit to 10032 (Operation not permitted), setting the max clients configuration to 3984.
[8719] 04 Feb 14:51:09.009 # Creating Server TCP listening socket *:6379: bind: Address already in use
```

Which mean I need to configure it, but all I want is the version!

So how do I check Redis server version?

Answer (score 428, accepted):

> $ redis-server --version

gives you the version.

Comment: This doesn't give you the currently running version though. I had upgraded a server to 3.2.8 via yum, and this command showed the new version, but the server needed to be restarted manually to launch the new version, whereas INFO correctly reported the old version.

Comment: @X-Cubed is right. I'm surprised this wrong answer is highly upvoted.

Comment: the advantage of `redis-server --version` is that it can be run even when the server is down (e.g. in a Jenkins pipeline when testing a Redis container), while `redis-cli info <subinfo>` will succeed only in a complete working setup, with `redis-server` running and responsive and with open network connectivity between `redis-cli` and `redis-server`

Comment: I landed here trying to figure out "I've got an application that's a client of a redis server, how do I discover its version?", where I'm not even able to login to the server.  Issuing the `info` command got me the answer.  (Which, reading more carefully, wouldn't have helped OP.  Still, I think most readers will find issuing `info` from a client more helpful than running `redis-server` on the host.

Comment: Podman container version: `podman exec -it redis sh -c "redis-server --version"`

Answer (score 241):

Run the command [`INFO`](http://redis.io/commands/info). The version will be the first item displayed.

The advantage of this over *redis-server --version* is that sometimes you don't have access to the server (e.g. when it's provided to you on the cloud), in which case `INFO` is your only option.

Comment: when your redis fails to start — you can't have access to server: `Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused` So it's better to know where your redis-cli is and then asks through --version there

Comment: Gives you lots of other info too... such as key hits and misses and uptime.

Comment: @markthegrea valid point, I updated my answer since some people didn't see the advantage.

Comment: ```redis-cli INFO SERVER | grep redis_version```

Answer (score 57):

To support the answers given above,
The details of the redis instance can be obtained by

```
$ redis-cli
$ INFO
```

This gives all the info you may need

```sh
# Server
redis_version:5.0.5
redis_git_sha1:00000000
redis_git_dirty:0
redis_build_id:da75abdfe06a50f8
redis_mode:standalone
os:Linux 5.3.0-51-generic x86_64
arch_bits:64
multiplexing_api:epoll
atomicvar_api:atomic-builtin
gcc_version:7.5.0
process_id:14126
run_id:adfaeec5683d7381a2a175a2111f6159b6342830
tcp_port:6379
uptime_in_seconds:16860
uptime_in_days:0
hz:10
configured_hz:10
lru_clock:15766886
executable:/tmp/redis-5.0.5/src/redis-server
config_file:

# Clients
connected_clients:22
....More Verbose
```

The version lies in the second line :)

Answer (score 24):

There are two commands, which you can use to check the version of redis

```
    redis-server -v
```

or

```
    redis-server --version
```

Answer (score 18):

if you want to know a remote redis server's version,  just connect to that server and issue command "info server", you will get things like this:

```
...
redis_version:3.2.12
redis_git_sha1:00000000
redis_git_dirty:0
redis_build_id:9c3b73db5f7822b7
redis_mode:standalone
os:Linux 2.6.32.43-tlinux-1.0.26-default x86_64
arch_bits:64
multiplexing_api:epoll
gcc_version:4.9.4
process_id:5034
run_id:a45b2ffdc31d7f40a1652c235582d5d277eb5eec
```

Answer (score 11):

**To get the version of Redis server**

> redis-server -v

**To get the version of Redis client**

> redis-cli -v

Answer (score 3):

As noted in a comment by A. Tolstoy, you can use one of these:

```
$ redis.cli info server | grep ^redis_version:
redis_version:6.2.6

$ redis.cli info server | grep ^redis_version: | cut -d: -f2 
6.2.6

$ redis.cli info server | grep ^redis_version: | cut -d: -f2 | cut -d. -f-2
6.2
```