# How to find out Redis version

Tags: redis

I am on my box ubuntu 12.04 (precise32), where [Redis](http://redis.io/topics/quickstart) was installed, but I can not find out the Redis version. How can I resolve this problem?

It was installed using the [redisio cookbook](http://community.opscode.com/search?query=redisio&scope=cookbook).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to check redis instance version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21555942/how-to-check-redis-instance-version)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

- If you want to find the version of the server:

  ```
  $ redis-server -v
  ```

  For example in my system I get this result:

  ```
  Redis server v=2.8.4 sha=00000000:0 malloc=libc bits=64 build=92637893332b8579
  ```
- If you want to get the version of the client:

  ```
  $ redis-cli -v
  ```
- If you want to know the version of the server, *from the client*:

  ```
  > INFO
  ```

and the first line is the version of the Redis server.