# Check the version of Redis

Tags: python, redis

I'd like to check the version of redis,
it could be accomplished on command line

```
In [181]: !redis-server --version
Redis server v=4.0.10 sha=00000000:0 malloc=libc bits=64 build=ea14acb2d1b3b56f
```

However, when it return the redis-py's version rather than redis version if

```
In [184]: redis.__version__
Out[184]: '2.10.6
```

It could be achieved in a wieldy way

```
In [186]: subprocess.run("redis-server --version", shell=True)
Redis server v=4.0.10 sha=00000000:0 malloc=libc bits=64 build=ea14acb2d1b3b56f
Out[186]: CompletedProcess(args='redis-server --version', returncode=0)
```

How could I check the version of redis directly with pure code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to check redis instance version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21555942/how-to-check-redis-instance-version)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Redis has the `INFO` command to get all sort of info about the server:

```
import redis

r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
print(r.execute_command('INFO')['redis_version'])
```

Answer (score 1):

From the cli you can use following command

```
redis-cli info
```

Sample Output

```
# Server
redis_version:4.0.1
redis_git_sha1:00000000
redis_git_dirty:0
redis_build_id:f37081b32886670b
redis_mode:standalone
os:Darwin 16.7.0 x86_64
arch_bits:64
multiplexing_api:kqueue
atomicvar_api:atomic-builtin
gcc_version:4.2.1
```

or if you need version you can try with pipe cmd

```
redis-cli info | grep "redis_version"
```

Output

```
redis_version:4.0.1
```

i hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

Python Redis has the info function to get all info about redis server.
We can get the redis_version from this function output.

```
red = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
print(red.info().get('redis_version'))
```